# ¿Cómo exportar un archivo XLS a CSV delimitado por comas excluyendo filas?

Tags: c#, sql-server

mi pregunta es la siguiente.
Estoy construyendo una aplicación para insertar unos datos de forma automática de una aplicación a una BD.
El otro programa está automatizado para generar un XLS, y el problema recalca que con este archivo es que trae en la primera fila está el titulo de los campos y es algo innecesario, ya que lo que hago es de este xls exportarlo a CSV y luego llamar el procedimiento almacenado para insertar los datos a través de un bulk insert.

¿Hay alguna forma para parametrizar que no me exporte la primera fila del XLS a CSV?

Código acá:

```
 try
        {
            //ESTA PARTE SE ENCARGA DE COGER EL ARCHIVO XLS QUE GENERAMOS PARA PASARLO A CSV DELIMITADO POR COMAS (;)
            String fileNameorigen = "C://datos.xls";
            String fileNameDestino = "//argos/informatica$/temp/datos.csv";
            System.Text.Encoding.RegisterProvider(System.Text.CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
            using (var stream = File.Open(fileNameorigen, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
                {
                    IExcelDataReader excelReaderXls = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);                        
                    string csvData = string.Format("{0};{1};{2};{3};{4};{5};{6};{7};{8};{9}", "Indice", "Hora", "Puerta", "Num", "Nombre", "Departamento", "Departamento", "ID Usuario", "Estado", "Detalle");
                    int row = 0;
                    while (excelReaderXls.Read())
                    {
                        if (row > 0)
                            csvData += string.Format("\"{0}\";\"{1}\";\"{2}\";\"{3}\";\"{4}\";\"{5}\";\"{6}\";\"{7}\";\"{8}\";\"{9}\"",
                                excelReaderXls.GetValue(0),    // Indice
                                excelReaderXls.GetString(1),   // Hora
                                excelReaderXls.GetString(2),   // Puerta
                                excelReaderXls.GetValue(3),    // Numero
                                excelReaderXls.GetString(4),   // Nombre
                                excelReaderXls.GetString(5),   // Departamento
                                excelReaderXls.GetString(6),   // Departamento
                                excelReaderXls.GetString(7),   // ID Usuario
                                excelReaderXls.GetString(8),   // Estado
                                excelReaderXls.GetString(9));  // Detalle

                        csvData += "\n";
                        row++;
                    }
                    // Free resources (IExcelDataReader is IDisposable)
                    excelReaderXls.Close();
                    // define tu propia salida de archivo csv ( en este caso lo mandé a mi unidad extraible )                       
                    StreamWriter csv = new StreamWriter(fileNameDestino, false);
                    csv.Write(csvData);
                    csv.Close();                      
                }   
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var exx = ex;
            Trace.WriteLine("Error" + exx);
        }
```

O si existe la posibilidad de insertar directamente los datos del xls a la BD exluyendo esa línea de forma automática, por favor compartirla.

Gracias por leer.

Comment: Del sitio en ingles [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36068256/t-sql-bulk-insert-skipping-first-row-with-or-without-header)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probaste de la siguiente manera? para evitar el primero registro?

```
  if (excelReaderXls.RowCount > 0)
                        {
                            for (int i = 1; i < excelReaderXls.RowCount; i++)
                            {
                                csvData += string.Format("\"{0}\";\"{1}\";\"{2}\";\"{3}\";\"{4}\";\"{5}\";\"{6}\";\"{7}\";\"{8}\";\"{9}\"",
                                    excelReaderXls.GetValue(0),    // Indice
                                    excelReaderXls.GetString(1),   // Hora
                                    excelReaderXls.GetString(2),   // Puerta
                                    excelReaderXls.GetValue(3),    // Numero
                                    excelReaderXls.GetString(4),   // Nombre
                                    excelReaderXls.GetString(5),   // Departamento
                                    excelReaderXls.GetString(6),   // Departamento
                                    excelReaderXls.GetString(7),   // ID Usuario
                                    excelReaderXls.GetString(8),   // Estado
                                    excelReaderXls.GetString(9));  // Detalle

                                csvData += "\n";
                                row++;

                            }
                        }
```